# How to find the coordinate of the center of a sphere made in 3D by voxels given all the coordinate of the voxels that made up the sphere

Tags: python, graph, 3d, linear-algebra, voxel

I have coordinate of all the voxels that make up the sphere
C = [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...,[xn,yn,zn]] (around 4000 coordinates)
Please teach me how I can get a coordinate that is the center of this sphere by Python code.

Because this is a sphere, so when I plot it and try to identify the center coordinate, I couldn't see where the center is. This would be easier in 2D (circle). I still have no clue where I can start from.
I expect the result to be

> > Ccenter = [x_center,y_center,z_center]

I am new to this community and to coding, you can give me feedback regarding the way I ask this question.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have an array of shape `(n, 3)`, `np.sum((Ccenter - C)**2, axis=1)-R**2` so you could get the coefficients of `x**2`, `y**2`, `z**2`, `x`, `y`, `z`.

```py
a,_,_,_ = np.linalg.lstsq(np.hstack([C**2, C]), np.ones(n), rcond=None)
Ccenter = -a[3:6] / (2*a[0])
```

A test example

```
import numpy as np
n = 4000; # a cloud of 4000 points
x = np.random.randn(n, 3)
# make them a standard sphere
x = x / np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2, 1, keepdims=True));

# Placement of the sphere
r = 7
center = [4,5,6]
C = r * x + center

# Discover the placement from the points
a,_,_,_ = np.linalg.lstsq(np.hstack([C**2, C]), np.ones(n), rcond=None)
print(-a[3:6] / (2*a[0]))
```